# cheked не работает в превдоклассе

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Доброго времени суток.

Есть разметка HTML

```
         <input id="check_1" type="checkbox" name="name">
         <label for="check_1" data-value="option1">Свитера</label>
```

Есть SASS

```
input[type="checkbox"]
    position: absolute
    left: -9999px

input[type="checkbox"] + label::after
    content: ""
    display: inline-block
    background: url("../images/sprite_check.jpg") 0 0 no-repeat
    width: 8px
    height: 8px

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after
    background-position-x: -8px
```

На выходе (CSS)

```
  input[type="checkbox"] {
      position: absolute;
      left: -9999px;}

input[type="checkbox"] + label::after {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    background: url("../images/sprite_check.jpg") 0 0 no-repeat;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px; }

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
    background-position-x: -8px; }
```

Делаю стилизацию checkbox c помощью превдокласса after и спрайта картинки!
Так вот, не осуществляется сдвиг фона на -8px,  такое ощущение, что checked вообще не рабочий элемент, в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  background: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/210284/check_radio_sheet.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
  width: 19px;
  height: 19px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
  background-position-x: -19px;
}
```

```html
<input id="check_1" type="checkbox" name="name"/>
<label for="check_1" data-value="option1">Свитера</label>
```

Comment: отличается ли данный код от кода в вопросе?